# ng-token-auth resolve function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple question (I think) about how to handle the resolve respond from my states. As I am using Ng-token-auth to handle authentication, in every state I have the following code:

```
 .state('dashboard',{
        url:'/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html.erb',
        controller: 'dashboard_ctrl',
        resolve: {
          auth: function($auth) {
            return $auth.validateUser();
            }
          }
      })
```

If i enter localhost:3000/dashboard I get a blank page. How can I handle that response to redirect to sign_in page??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $auth, $state){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(ev, error){
    console.log('You need to log in first'+ error);
    $state.go('sign_in', 'sign_in_error');
  });

});
```

Hope this help someone.